# react-date-range create custom inputRanges

Tags: reactjs, react-daterange-picker

I'm using the react-date-range component and want to add some of my own custom inputRanges on the left side of the interface. At the moment it has, yesterday, last week, last month etc. I want to add "this year", "last year", "12 months previous"

I'm able to remove the preset ranges by using

`inputRanges={[]}`

But I'm struggling to determine how to add my own ranges. I see the shape of the range object is:

```
{
   startDate: PropTypes.object,
   endDate: PropTypes.object,
   color: PropTypes.string,
   key: PropTypes.string,
   autoFocus: PropTypes.bool,
   disabled: PropTypes.bool,
   showDateDisplay: PropTypes.bool,
 }
```

but populating the object and passing it into inputRanges as an array element doesn't work either:

```
 inputRanges={[{
              startDate: new Date(),
              endDate: new Date(),
              color: "#eecc99",
              key: "Today",
              autoFocus: false,
              disabled: false,
              showDateDisplay: true,
            }]}
```

I'm reading the documentation here but it's not helping much: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `staticRanges` prop to the `DateRangePicker` component. Additionally, if you want to include the default ranges of the library, you can pass `...defaultStaticRanges`, as the first argument of the array.
You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-almeida-9kf3e?file=/src/App.js) for live working example.

```
import {
  addDays,
  endOfDay,
  startOfDay,
  startOfYear,
  startOfMonth,
  endOfMonth,
  endOfYear,
  addMonths,
  addYears,
  startOfWeek,
  endOfWeek,
  isSameDay,
  differenceInCalendarDays
} from "date-fns";
import { useState } from "react";
import { DateRangePicker, defaultStaticRanges } from "react-date-range";
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css"; // main css file
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css"; // theme css file
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: addDays(new Date(), 7),
      key: "selection"
    }
  ]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DateRangePicker
        onChange={(item) => setState([item.selection])}
        showSelectionPreview={true}
        moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
        months={2}
        ranges={state}
        direction="horizontal"
        staticRanges={[
          ...defaultStaticRanges,
          {
            label: "last year",
            range: () => ({
              startDate: startOfYear(addYears(new Date(), -1)),
              endDate: endOfYear(addYears(new Date(), -1))
            }),
            isSelected(range) {
              const definedRange = this.range();
              return (
                isSameDay(range.startDate, definedRange.startDate) &&
                isSameDay(range.endDate, definedRange.endDate)
              );
            }
          },
          {
            label: "this year",
            range: () => ({
              startDate: startOfYear(new Date()),
              endDate: endOfDay(new Date())
            }),
            isSelected(range) {
              const definedRange = this.range();
              return (
                isSameDay(range.startDate, definedRange.startDate) &&
                isSameDay(range.endDate, definedRange.endDate)
              );
            }
          }
        ]}
      />
      ;
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want to remove just one of the default input ranges or change the label you can do something like this.

```
import { DateRangePicker, defaultInputRanges } from 'react-date-range';

     <DateRangePicker
          ...props
          inputRanges={[{
            ...defaultInputRanges[0],
            label: 'Your new label'
          }]}
        />
```